# Design Mode Error "Object does not match target type" for Loaded Page Resource

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, silverlight, design-data

I am currently attempting to mock up data for my view by utilizing Design Data for my ViewModel. Specifically, I have a View front end, and a ViewModel backend for my silverlight application.

When I have mocked up other views, things have worked perfectly. Even in this particular view, the only issue seems to have to be with collections.

Any idea why my "CategoryItem" keeps giving me an error when I try to assign a value to "CategoryName"? I have no idea what is causing the issue...

Code below:

My Design Data:

```
<vm:MainPageViewModel
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WebCatalog.ViewModels"    
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:WebCatalog.Models"   
    SelectedTab="Category 1"
    ProjectName="New Project Name"
    ShowPopup="False"
    IsBusy="False"
    CurrentUser="Alex"
    >
    <vm:MainPageViewModel.Categories>
        <m:CategoryItem CategoryName="test"/>
    </vm:MainPageViewModel.Categories>


</vm:MainPageViewModel>
```

My simplified ViewModel:

```
public class MainPageViewModel {
    public string SelectedTab {get;set;}
    public string ProjectName {get;set;}
    public bool ShowPopup {get;set;}
    public bool IsBusy {get;set;}
    public string CurrentUser {get;set;}

    public ObservableCollection<CategoryItem> Categories {get;private set;}

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
         Categories = new ObservableCollection<CategoryItem>();
    }
}
```

Finally, my (simplified) view:

```
<UserControl 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=../SampleData/MainWindowSampleData.xaml}">
<!-- Decision Categories -->
                <StackPanel Width="200" toolkit:DockPanel.Dock="Left" Height="100">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentUser}">meep</TextBlock>
                    <ItemsControl Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock>Itemalkdjfa;ldfj;lakdsjfladfjal;dfjaldfja</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>

                </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Why not try it in VS2015 community edition and see if the same occurs? This issue may have been resolved in a later version.

Answer (score 0):

On your VM change

```
public ObservableCollection<CategoryItem> Categories {get;private set;}
```

to

```
public ObservableCollection<CategoryItem> Categories {get;set;}
```

---

Otherwise my sample xaml binding looked and worked in design mode like this:

```
<local:MainVM x:Key="myMainVM">
    <local:MainVM.Categories>
        <local:CategoryItem Name="Test" />
    </local:MainVM.Categories>
</local:MainVM>
```

...

```
<ListBox DataContext="{StaticResource myMainVM}" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/></DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Where the VM mirrored yours (sans the private set) and the VM was loaded in Xaml on Silverlight and showed the data in design mode.

```
public class MainVM
{

    public ObservableCollection<CategoryItem> Categories { get; set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        Categories = new ObservableCollection<CategoryItem>();
    }

}

public class CategoryItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks OmegaMan, unfortunately that didn't work (I had tried that earlier). I am still getting "Object does not match target type" as an error in my DesignData xaml. If I don't have any "CategoryItem"s, it works fine, it simply doesn't want to add any items to the collection... Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Aerophilic Maybe create a simplified test program...possibly in doing so you can an find the ultimate difference. As mentioned, my basic one above works. GL

Comment: @Aerophilic is `CategoryItem` a public class?

Comment: Yup... I got it to work with a different view, so I am in process of simplifying my mainwindow view to figure out what the culprit is. I suspect that there is some property that is using a service that is causing headaches...

Comment: Okay, figured it out. Apparently DesignData pukes when you have a non-local reference as a property. In my specific case, I had exposed a "WebClient" as a property. Still don't know why this caused an issue, so if anyone could tell me why, you'll get my "answered" for this solution. If I have time, I'll update the question to make it more specific to what was actually wrong.

Comment: I had the same issue. When I open it in Blend, it's ok. It's showing the design time data and everything looks normal. So I decided to restart visual studio, then the errors are gone.